# How to use gcp_compute_instance_info to fetch a particular disk

Tags: ansible

I have a GCP instance that has 3 disks: boot disk, data disk, and a temp disk. I want to use a Ansible module like gcp_compute_instance_info to find the data disk name:

```
     - name: found the data disk
       gcp_compute_instance_info:
         zone: "{{ gcp_zone }}"
         filters:
         - name = "{{ host }}"
         project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
         auth_kind: "{{ gcp_auth_kind }}"
         service_account_file: "{{ gcp_acct_file }}"
       register: inst_reg

     - debug: msg="{{ inst_reg.resources[0].disks[0].deviceName }}"
```

This only gives me one disk name,

```
TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************
Friday 03 June 2022  00:46:08 +0000 (0:00:00.762)       0:00:03.198 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "abc-prod"
}
```

which is the boot disk.

I know it is because the `disks[0]`, but how do I find the data disk name?

For server `abc-prod`, the disks are:

```
abc-prod
abc-prod-data (or abc-prod-data-2022-01-01-05-23-22)
abc-prod-temp
```

The data disk name will be in the format of `abc-prod-data`, or `abc-prod-data-2022-01-01-05-23-22` which has a time stamp.

I need to retrieve the data disk and then create a snapshot of it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the extra code that works and it picks up the data disk:

```
    - set_fact:
        disk_list: "{{ inst_reg.resources[0]| community.general.json_query('disks[*].deviceName') | list }}"

    - debug: msg="{{ disk_list }}"

    - set_fact:
        target_disk: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ disk_list }}"
      when: item | regex_search("^(.*)-data(.*)$")

    - debug: msg="{{ target_disk }}"
```

and the output looks like this for data disk without the time stamp:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************Friday 03 June 2022  03:07:38 +0000 (0:00:00.181)       0:00:03.290 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "abc-test",
        "abc-test-temp",
        "abc-test-data"
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************Friday 03 June 2022  03:07:38 +0000 (0:00:00.042)       0:00:03.332 *********** 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=abc-test) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=abc-test-temp) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc-test-data)

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************Friday 03 June 2022  03:07:38 +0000 (0:00:00.055)       0:00:03.388 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "abc-test-data"
}
```

or for the data disk has time stamp:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************Friday 03 June 2022  03:04:28 +0000 (0:00:00.172)       0:00:03.252 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "abc-prod",
        "abc-prod-temp",
        "abc-prod-data-2022-06-03-01-01-54"
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] ************************************************************************************Friday 03 June 2022  03:04:28 +0000 (0:00:00.041)       0:00:03.294 *********** 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=abc-prod) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=abc-prod-temp) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=abc-prod-data-2022-06-03-01-01-54)

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************Friday 03 June 2022  03:04:29 +0000 (0:00:00.093)       0:00:03.387 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "abc-prod-data-2022-06-03-01-01-54"
}
```